# Remove last character on input field jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this kind of question has been asked several times but none of the answers worked for me. I want to make my own spell-checker which compares words letter by letter and checks the correctness. 
As user types letters one by one, the content is checked. If it is correct, goes on, if it is wrong: I want the last letter to be deleted.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z22mc/) is my code:

```
var word = [];
word = "beautiful".split('');
var i =0;

$(document).ready(
function() 
{ $('#txtword').keyup(
 function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('txtword').value;
    if (value[i] == word[i]){ 
            alert("Right letter!");
            i++; }
            else
            { alert("Wrong letter");
            value.slice(0,-1);
            /*value.substr(0,value.length-1);*/
            }
        });
    })
```

I tried both options `value.slice(0,-1);` and `value.substr(0,value.length-1);` but they are not working. Can someone help me find the mistake!

Comment: You're not assigning the value to anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign *new* value back to `value` property of the element

```
this.value = value.substr(0,value.length-1);
```

**Note:** You can use `this.value` instead of  `document.getElementById('txtword').value;`